Action is not mapping by Custom router in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API
In my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project written in C#, we need to route the below endpoints to a single action method with a custom route in the API.
Here is my code - CustomRouter:
public class CustomRouter : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _defaultRouter;

    public CustomRouter(IRouter defaultRouter)
    {
        _defaultRouter = defaultRouter;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        // Extract the path and query string from the request
        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
        var queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        // Split the path into segments to extract controller name and entity name
        var pathSegments = path.Split('/');
        var controllerName = pathSegments.Length > 1 ? pathSegments[pathSegments.Length - 2] : string.Empty;
        var entityName = pathSegments.Length > 0 ? pathSegments[pathSegments.Length - 1] : string.Empty;
        var queryParameters = queryString.HasValue ? queryString.Value : string.Empty;

        // Check if the request is a GET request and targeting the InsightsController
        if (controllerName.Equals("insights", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            context.HttpContext.Request.Method.Equals("GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Set RouteData for controller and action
            context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Insights";
            context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "GetTest"; // The action method to invoke
            context.RouteData.Values["entity"] = entityName; // Pass entity name
            context.RouteData.Values["queryParameters"] = queryParameters; // Pass query parameters if needed

            context.HttpContext.Request.Path = new PathString("/api/v1/Insights/");
            context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString();
            // Pass the request to the default router or the next middleware, which will handle invoking the controller
            await _defaultRouter.RouteAsync(context);
            return;
        }

        // If no match is found, delegate to the next middleware
        await _defaultRouter.RouteAsync(context);
    }
         public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        // Generate virtual path if needed
        return _defaultRouter.GetVirtualPath(context);
    }
}

Add use of the custom router in the Startup class:
// Use Custom Router
app.UseRouter(builder =>
  {
     // Create default router to pass to CustomRouter
     var defaultRouter = builder.Build();

     // Register the CustomRouter
     builder.Routes.Add(new CustomRouter(defaultRouter));                  
  });

Controller class:
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class InsightsController : Controller
{
     [HttpGet]
     public async Task<string> Get(string entity, string id = default)
     {
     }
}

The custom router has been added. Despite of having the custom router,
The Insights Controller Get method is mapped and executed for this request
http://localhost:63896/api/v1/Insights
But not for the below request
http://localhost:63896/api/v1/Insights/pdrsearch?rs:q=bug
Googled for any help/code example and also tried adding customMiddleware.
No luck yet.

The logic in your codes look good and it worked for http://localhost:63896/api/v1/Insights. Could you please share your debug info? I mean you might compare the debug info between the 2 requests, and see why it doesn't work for /api/v1/Insights/pdrsearch?rs:q=bug
